# Calculate how many ways you can roll a 6 with two dice?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

How would I answer this question (is there a way to do it on a calc?)

$2 + 4 = 6$

$3 + 3 = 6$

$4 + 2 = 6$

$5 + 1 = 6$

$1 + 5 = 6$

so $5$ ways is the answer?

Comment: Yes, if as usual we consider the two dice to be distinct. To do it if you are holding a calculator, first put down the calculator. Your list is correct. It might have been better, for harder problems, to make the listing more systematic.

Comment: Roll a six? Or roll a SUM equal to six? There are three ways to roll where a six appears. Die A, Die B, or both Dice A and B. Each of these possibilities the given die appears as a six.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for these types of problems I use tree diagrams, but since it's a problem of two dice either method works:

[image]

Comment: Is there a more generalized way; i.e. such that $f(n) = s$, where $n$ denotes number of dice used, and $s$ denotes number of solutions which yield $6$?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, however I am not that proficient at Stats and/or Probability, so someone can correct me if there is indeed a formula for it.

Comment: For sum $6$, the number of dice is $1$ to $6$. It turns out that if there are $n$ dice, the number of ways is $\binom{5}{n-1}$. This can be done by a **Stars and Bars** argument. But the idea does not generalize simply to "big" sums. There are ways through generating functions, not very pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is a way to do it on a calculator!

Let $x_1$ be the result of the first dice and $x_2$ the other's. Clearly, $x_1 + x_2 = 6$ where $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

Now think of six $1$s side to side and you put a wall inbetween. You can do this in $5\choose1$ different ways.

Where you had $r$ dices and you wanted to roll a $n$, for example; instead of listing all the solutions, you could simply use $(r-1)$ walls and the result would be $n-1\choose r-1$

**Edit:** Now my answer seems redundant after seeing @André Nicolas's comment but I don't know if I should delete it.

Comment: So, would this be nPr or nCr on a calculator?